# nouislider callback function when minval

Tags: nouislider

I'm using the the NoUiSlider 7 (jQuery Version) and i want a callback function if the User types a value below min value.

```
$('#slider').noUiSlider({
            start: 100,
            step: 10,
            range: {
                'min': Number(range[0]),
                'max': Number(range[1])
            },
            serialization: {
                lower: [
                    $.Link({
                        target: $('#ausgabe_klassisch_betrag')
                    })
                ],
                format: {
                    thousand: '.',
                    postfix: ' E',
                    mark: ',',
                    decimals:0
                }
            }
        });
```

So i tried to slice the value (because i use 2 characters postfix) and if the value is below then alert:

```
$("#slider_klassisch_betrag").on({
            change: function(){
                $val = $("#slider_klassisch_betrag").val().slice(0,-1);
                if($val < 30 ){ alert(); }
            }
        });
```

But this does not work. the change only works if the slider changes and not with change by the input field

Comment: This happens because the slider `Link`s to the input by attaching a change event of its own. The slider's change event is handled first.

Comment: so what's the solution? is it possible to write the change function inside the init function?